# Ubuntu update messed up scrolling behavior: How to fix?

Tags: scrolling

I recently did an Ubuntu update to version 22.04 LTS and after this update the scrolling behavior is bugged. Before this we had two scrolling options: (1) Normal scrolling and a weird (2) "Natural scrolling". We could turn off natural scrolling so it was never a problem. However, after the update the default behavior was changed to 'Natural scrolling' and turning off this option in settings is not making any difference. How can we fix this? I want to get rid of natural scrolling and bring back normal scrolling.

Comment: On my system, the only visible difference is: when I turn the scroll wheel on the mouse towards me in default scrolling mode, the page scrolls down. When I do that in "natural scrolling" mode, the page scrolls up. Which is it in your case?

Comment: Hi,  the mouse wheel behavior is the same. The problem is there only for the trackpad. In the trackpad, we only have the second option. No matter if we turn on or off the natural scrolling switch.

Comment: The trackpad in either mode behaves the same on my system as the mouse: sliding two fingers south moves the page down in normal mode, up in "natural scolling". Did you search online (or this site) for bugs in the trackpad software associated with the brand of your laptop?

Comment: Yes, I could not find anything. Plus, the trackpad was working fine until I did an update.

Comment: If you run X11 rather than Wayland, you may try adjusting things using [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad).

Comment: Hi, Thanks this did the job.